# Array Index out of bound exception for replacing space with '%20'

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I am having trouble with my code. as i run the program it displays array index out of bound exception.Please suggest what are the errors in the code.

```
package replacespace;

import java.util.Scanner;



public class ReplaceSpace {

   /*public  int calLength(char par1[]){
       int count=0;
       for(char c:par1){
            count++;
       }
       return(count);
   }*/

    /**
     *
     * @param args
     */
    public void replaceSpace(char str[], int length){
         char[] newArray= new char[length+1];
         newArray[length+1]='\0';
         int position=0;
         for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
             if(str[i]==' '){
                 length=length+2;
                 newArray[position]='%';
                 newArray[position+1]='2';
                 newArray[position+2]='0';
                 position=position+3;

             }
             else{
                 newArray[position]=str[i];
                 position++;
             }
         }
         String s=new String(newArray);
             System.out.println(s);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ReplaceSpace rs= new ReplaceSpace();
        String s1,sCopy;

       int length;
       Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Please enter any string");
       s1=scan.nextLine();
       length=s1.length();
       char stringArr[]=new char[length];
       stringArr =s1.toCharArray();

       //length=rs.calLength(stringArr);

        rs.replaceSpace(stringArr,stringArr.length);
   }

}
```

this code is suppose to replace space in string with '%20'.

Comment: `string.replace(" ", "%20")`?

Comment: This code is highly confusing. Consider not using names like array, and StringArr1, s1 and so on for your variables. Gives things names that say what they are. You see, this code is simply written in such a complicated way that understanding its intent ... is like a major task. Seriously: focus on writing code that is easy to read. You know: when your code is easy to read, you will also find it much easier to find bugs in your code. As starter, you might want to look into "CleanCode" by Robert Martin.

Comment: Why is it surprising that you're getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`? You increase the value of the integer `length`, but that does not increase the actual length of `stringArr1`, and then you try to go as far as 5 past the end of the array (`length = length + 2` and looping until `j <= length`, indexing at `j + 3`)

Comment: I can't use inbuilt  methods such as replace

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int j=var1;j<=length;j++){
                   stringArr1[j]= '%';
                  stringArr1[j+1]='2';
                  stringArr1[i+2]='0';
                   stringArr1[j+3]=array[i+1];
               }
```

This code runs until j is equal to length.
you can not have `[j+3]` index for that iteration (or the one(s)) before.

Change your `j<=length` to `j<=(length-3)` (or similar)

But my recommendation: use Strings `replace` or `replaceAll` method

Comment: Or use a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: It should be noted that `length - 3` isn't enough. `length` is increased by 2 before every time that loop is run

Comment: @jonhopkins indeed. I just checked the indices as being 'will be augmented'. I wasn't sure by how much they were augmented which is why I set the (or similar).

Comment: My bad, I didn't see the (or similar). But in the end, it should just be `j < length` with the actual array being reallocated with the additional length before the loop. For the purposes of this exercise anyway. Really your recommendation for `String`'s replacement methods is the best option.

Comment: Still showing same error

Comment: what (exactly) did you change, and what does the complete stacktrace say?